# Cutting ' \0' from strings

Tags: c, string, strstr

I have a 2D array of strings loaded with getline from stdin example :

```
Hi my name is John.
I like chocolate.
```

Then i want to search if entered string / substring matches with one of the string arrays example :

```
Ohn. - matches at line 1
chocolate. - matches at line 2
```

I'm using standart function strstr :

```
if ( ( strstr(array[i],string) ) != NULL ) {
      printf("Match");
}
```

The problem is that when i want to find a string which is not at the end of the string like i wrote , it does not match because probably when i want to find "like" in the string it probably compares like\0 with "like" so it will never match.

When i load the line with getline to buffer i used function: strlen(buffer)-1 then i allocated memory for strlen(buffer) - 1 * sizeof(char) and then copied it to the array with memcpy function. Everything worked perfectly but when the string has lenght of 7-8 it puts 2 undefined characters at the end of the string example :

```
Enter string :testtttt
memcpy to allocated array of strlen(string) - 1
printed string from array looks like : testttttt1� or testtttttqx etc..
```

Strings with length less then 7 or more than 8 characters work perfectly. If you know how to fix this problem or know a better way to make from string\0 just string without \0 let me know i will be thankful.

Part of the code which does not work. Only matches wtith ending strings like i mentioned.Pole is 2D array of strings, line is buffer where the string is stored.

```
size_t len = 0;
char *line = NULL;
int number;
while ( (number = getline(&line, &len, stdin ) ) != -1 ) {
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if(strstr(pole[i], line) != NULL) {
               printf("Match");
            }
    }
}


    6 
John.

'Hi my name is John.
' contain 'John.
'
'Testing stuff
' does not contain 'John.
'
'I do not know what to write
' does not contain 'John.
'
8 
Testing

'Hi my name is John.
' does not contain 'Testing
'
'Testing stuff
' does not contain 'Testing
'
'I do not know what to write
' does not contain 'Testing
'
5 
know

'Hi my name is John.
' does not contain 'know
'
'Testing stuff
' does not contain 'know
'
'I do not know what to write
' does not contain 'know
'
```

Comment: A string is an array of characters ending with a \0. If it doesn't end with a \0, it's not a string. Also, strstr does **not** count the \0.

Comment: So can you then tell me why it does not match all string or substrings ?

Comment: can you edit the question with the code snippet that you've written?

Comment: @paxie Nope, but I know this isn't your problem.

Comment: Also, you *have* got a "string without \0". As you've found out, the \0 is actually there for a reason, which is so that functions like printf and strstr can tell where the end of the string is!

Comment: `sizeof(char)` allways equal 1 by definition - there is no need to multiply `strlen(buffer) - 1` by `sizeof(char)`.  Rather than *describing* your code, it would be much simpler to just post it.  Then we might see what your real problem is.  If you have a problem, it is never a good idea to hypothesise what that problem might be (if you knew enough to make a valid hypothesis, you probably would not have a problem)  - just ask the question.

Comment: *"Strings with length less then 7 or more than 8 characters work perfectly."* - by luck, not judgement.  Probably due to 8 byte alignment of the allocation.

Comment: Is this even *real* code!?  `if (strstr(array[i],string)) != NULL` is invalid - the  `!= NULL` is outside the parenthesis.  We cannot hope to solve your problem from code that is not the code with the problem or descriptions of code rather than *actual* code!

Comment: *"Pole is 2D array of strings" - did you really mean that, or is it just an *array of strings* (which would be a 2D array of `char`s). You are certainly using as an *array of strings* in this code.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit because you removed all context than made the accepted answer make any sense.  Improving a question is fair;  changing a question when it already has an acceptable answer is not.  If you no longer think the question is valid, you should delete it, and perhaps ask a new question.  The part about your test with "testtttt" is irrelevant, but that was the part you retained in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is evident in your debug output. `getline` does not strip the newline from the input, so for example you are searching for:

```
"know\n"
```

in

```
"I do not know what to write\n"
```

So your problem is not about stripping the `\0` string terminator, but rather stripping the `\n` line-end.

That can be achieved in a number of ways, for example:

```
char* newline = strrchr( line, '\n' ) ;
if( newlineaddr != NULL )
{
    *newlineaddr  = '\0' ;
}
```

or

```
size_t newlineindex = strcspn(line, "\n") ;
line[newlineindex] = '\0' ;
```

The first copes with multi-line input (not needed in this case) - only removing the last newline, while the second is more succinct.

Comment: Posted code  and the result after printing two compared strings.

Comment: Yes thank you that was the problem.

Comment: @paxie : The issue would have been immediately obvious when you observed the strings in a debugger.

Comment: Your proposed solution will crash if there is no `'\n'` in `line`, which will happen if the last line of the file does not end with a line feed. A more general solution is `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: @chqrlie : Good suggestion, though in this case the use of `getline()` ensures a newline.  The use of the reverse search was to allow matching multiple lines by only removing the last newline, but again that will never be the case for `getline()`.  As I said - a number of ways - the suggestion was not intended to be a recommendation.  The OP should consider his choices, and in this case your suggestion would probably be most appropriate.  Stealing your idea right now, and fixing the potential null dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through a function in c is very easy.You can use strcmp for comparison and strcmp comes with different flavours of it like stricmp,strncmp and so on...Here is the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

Comment: "Searching through a *function*"?  Did you mean "searching *using* a function" or "searching through a *string*"?  But that is not an answer to the question in any case. Searching for a substring is directly supported by the standard library using `strstr()`  Doing the same thing in a different way will not solve the problem here which is that the string really does not exist in the line - because it has a stray `\n` appended.

Comment: ... to be fair, @paxie changed the question *after* accepting an answer, so I can see how you might have thought this was helpful.  I have rolled-back the question to maintain context.